# Eclipse dll breakpoint

Tags: eclipse, debugging, dll, breakpoints

I have two projects in my Eclipse Workspace. The first one builds a dll while the other one is an executable which uses that dll. I would like to be able to set a breakpoint into the dll so that when I run the executable it stops in the dll code.
Anyone knows if this is possible? If yes what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself.
Simply use the --export-all-symbols in dllwrap to compile the dll, like:

```
$(DLLWRAP) --export-all-symbols -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias --def $(INPUTDEF) --output-exp $(OUTPUTEXP) --implib $(STATICLIB)  $(LINKOBJ) $(LIBS) -o $(BIN)
```